# References as Optional Function Arguments

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a function with an optional reference. I would like to be able to use it like this:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 557483943;

    test_function(x, None);

    let params = parameters(x);
    test_function(x, Some(&params));
}
```

where `parameters(x)` may take some time to execute. Therefore I would like to be able to pass an optional reference to the function. For now I use this as test code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Parameters {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

pub fn parameters(x: u32) -> Parameters {
    // would be a tedious calculation...
    let a = x / 6453;
    let b = x % 589703;
    Parameters { a, b }
}
```

What I came up with is this:

```
pub fn test_function(x: u32, params: Option<&Parameters>) {
    // tmp_params is needed as owner of the return value of 
    // parameters(x) that outlives the match statement
    let tmp_params: Parameters;

    let params = match params {
        Some(params) => params,
        None => {
            tmp_params = parameters(x);
            &tmp_params
        },
    };
    println!("params: {:?}", &params);
}
```

which works, but I am not sure if this is the idiomatic way to do this in rust.

Is there a way to avoid `tmp_params` and have the `Parameters` created in the `match` statement outlive the `match` statement itself?

Is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you wish to use `Option<&Parameters>` instead of just `Option<Parameters>`. With an option reference, if you call `test_function` with `None` for `params`, the params will be created locally and destroyed at the end of the call. If you can include some more surrounding information about your usecase, there might be a completely different way of approaching this. Otherwise, given the context, your current approach seems reasonable.

Comment: @sshashank124 i do not want to move `params` into the `test_function`. `params` needs to be usable after the function call (as in my example in the `println!("params: {:?}", &params);` line).

Comment: problem for me is that your [mcve] is odd, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca122a64db17804c14088c465d70707a) is currently better in your code. >To be more clear, why `test_function` would create a "default" parameter and drop it just after ? specially if it's take time to create. Other way why not just [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf47b89d36361592eec13799b4adeb42) let user do it ?

Comment: hmm... coming from python it is very idiomatic to have sth like `def `test_function(x: int, params: Optional[Parameters]=None)`. maybe this is not done in rust?
the example may be a bit contrived. but it is not exceptional that (prercomputed) data may be re-used?

Comment: Well, in that case use a hashmap, like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d41325063c1f3fcf6f5f6ec9158f8da) or use a meta function that will handle the cache for your function, or [use a structure and cache the result](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ebe9cd39d8f3d2a61cd5ca4e9cb3495a)

Comment: while i like your hashmap approach it is more of a meomize pattern, right? what i originally wanted was just an option to pass the values precomputed if they exist already - or to compute them within the function and drop them afterwards.

Comment: In that case, what you have is perfectly fine. Although I agree with @Stargateur, it's a bit of an odd set of requirements

Comment: like the two type differ you could similar to one of my previous example, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78fe9e982119e72bbc38a7d4992b2211) or use [either](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65b175cdc467d37543cf488257cd35e4)

Comment: @Stargateur thanks a lot for your effort! i will have a close look at your suggestions tomorrow!

Comment: @Stargateur i like [this one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78fe9e982119e72bbc38a7d4992b2211) a lot. i may end up using it. feel free to post it (or any of the others) as answer.